# "Global" topologies between compact convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally compact (but not compact), second countable, Hausdorff spaces with $Y$ metric.  It is easy to see that the [topology of compact convergence](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topology_of_compact_convergence) is weaker than the topology of uniform convergence on $C(X,Y)$ defined by the (possibly infinite) metric
$$
d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in X} | g(x)-f(x)|.
$$

The former has a very "local nature" and is very weak while the latter is a bit unruly which makes me look elsewhere.  What (studied) topologies lie in between these two?  Ideally, the topology should not be "of a local nature".

**Edit:** *Ideally this topology on $C(X,Y)$ should be stronger than the topology of compact-convergence but also have a nice criterion to verify density (like the Stone-Weirestrass theorem) when $Y=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X$ is "nice".*

Comment: Given any set $\mathfrak{S}$ of subsets of $X$, Bourbaki (*General Topology* X, §1) defines the topology (in fact, the uniform structure) of $\mathfrak{S}$-convergence. You can take  $\mathfrak{S}=\{X\} $ (giving uniform convergence), $\mathfrak{S}=$ compact, precompact, bounded... your choice.

Comment: Ah, these are the set-open topologies no?

Comment: Probably (I don't know what the set-open topologies are).

Comment: For a discussion of difference between set open topologies with convergence on sets topologies see Mccoy, Ntantu - topological properties of spaces of continuous functions

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions. For a question like this, it can be useful to look at special cases for pointers. Here I would suggest firstly the case where $X$ is the integers (then your space is $Y^N$ with the box, resp., the product  topology—an interesting further specialisation is where $Y$ is also the integers, i.e., your space is the irrationals). Secondly,  where the image spaces is the reals, in which case you get the standard Fréchet space $C(X)$.

Comment: It is hard to make a useful comment without knowing what you have in mind, but one method for extrapolating between your two cases is to use so-called weighted seminorms or pseudometrics.